# How to access file system with adb shell for the work profile

Tags: adb, android-enterprise

With the command "adb shell ls", only the files for the private user are listed. How to access the files for the work profiles? There is no argument to specify the user, like the am command has.

Comment: does the answer below help in figuring out the issue?

Comment: DUP: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221122